# NestJs Cache Manager taking global ttl value

Tags: nestjs, node-redis

I have registered redis as cache manager in nestjs which is taking default value from env of 0 i.e no limit which is needed for some keys. But I want to pass custom ttl to another key using set(key, value, ttl) which is still taking ttl from env not from set function.

- node: v18.14.2
- cache-manager: 5.1.6
- cache-manager-redis-store: 3.0.1

**redis module**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [],
      useFactory: async (
        config: ConfigType<typeof configuration>,
      ): RedisClientOptions => ({
        store: redisStore,
        socket: {
          host: config.redis.host,
          port: config.redis.port,
          tls: config.redis.tls,
        },
        ttl: parseInt(config.redis.ttl, 10),
      }),
      inject: [configuration.KEY],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [RedisService],
  exports: [RedisService],
})
export class RedisModule {}
```

**redis service**

```
import { CACHE_MANAGER, Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';

@Injectable()
export class RedisService {
  constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cache: Cache) {}

  async setWithTtl(
    key: string | number,
    value: any,
  ): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.cache.set(
        JSON.stringify(key),
        JSON.stringify(value),
        500,
      );
      return;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

After some research I found the answer. Update the set function to

```
await this.cache.set(
    JSON.stringify(key),
    JSON.stringify(value),
    { ttl: 500 } as any,
  );
```

> Here 500 must be in seconds not in milliseconds even if cache-manager is v5

More details about the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/dabroek/node-cache-manager-redis-store/issues/40#issuecomment-1318816820)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you are facing this situation?

> WARNING
> cache-manager version 4 uses seconds for TTL (Time-To-Live). The current version of cache-manager (v5) has switched to using milliseconds instead. NestJS doesn't convert the value, and simply forwards the ttl you provide to the library. In other words:
> If using cache-manager v4, provide ttl in seconds
> If using cache-manager v5, provide ttl in milliseconds
> Documentation is referring to seconds, since NestJS was released targeting version 4 of cache-manager.

Comment: The time unit isn't the issue here. When I add 0 as ttl in env, the key ttl is still no limit and not taking any number passed to `this.cache.set()`

Answer (score 0):

The types are wrong in this case, when using redis the third option should be like {ttl: number} but as third argument from cache-manager is expecting ttl?:number